# Process a file that starts with a BOM (FF FE)

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, unicode

I received a .csv file with the `FF FE` BOM:

```
$ head -n1 dotan.csv | hd
00000000  ff fe 41 00 64 00 20 00  67 00 72 00 6f 00 75 00  |..A.d. .g.r.o.u.|
```

When using `awk` to parse it I'm getting a bunch of null bytes, which I suspect is due to the byte order. How can I swap the byte order on this file (using the CLI) so that normal tools will work with it?

Note that I think that this file is only ASCII characters (except for the BOM), but I cannot confirm that as `grep` thinks that it is a binary file:

```
$ grep -P '^[\x00-\x7f]' dotan.csv 
Binary file dotan.csv matches
```

Searching for the same string in VIM shows *every character* matching!

Using `iconv` to convert to ASCII does not get rid of \x00 values, actually it makes the problem worse as now they look like null bytes instead of UTF-8!

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII dotan.csv > fixed.txt 
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0

$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//IGNORE dotan.csv > fixed.txt

$ head -n1 fixed.txt | hd
00000000  41 00 64 00 20 00 67 00  72 00 6f 00 75 00 70 00  |A.d. .g.r.o.u.p.|
```

**How can I swap the byte order on this file (using the CLI) so that normal tools will work with it?**

Comment: The CSV file you created in Windows or Mac?

Comment: Can you give a portion of file?

Comment: [Here is a link](http://dotancohen.com/example.csv) to an anonymized portion of the file which preserves the unique problems with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), `FF FE` means `UTF16LE`. So you should tell `iconv` to convert from `UTF16LE` to `UTF8`:

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 dotan.csv > fixed.txt
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I had the UTF-8 and UTF-16 BOM mixed up: I thought that FFFE and FEFF were UTF-8 and I never knew the UTF-16 BOM(s). Actually, those are UTF-16 BOMs, and I never knew the (useless) UTF-8 BOM!.

Comment: @dotancohen: I test in my Fedora and the `tail` solution works fine. What OS do you use?

Comment: This doesn't work (i.e. remove the BOM) for version "iconv (GNU libiconv 1.14)" in Git Bash on Windows. [But (for whatver reason) using just `UTF-16` instead of one of the byte-order versions works.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11571759/173497)

Answer (score 5):

`dos2unix` also removes BOMs and converts UTF-16 to UTF-8:

```
$ printf %s あ|recode ..utf16 >a;xxd -p a;dos2unix a;xxd -p a
feff3042
dos2unix: converting file a to Unix format...
e38182
```

`dos2unix` also removes UTF-8 BOMs:

```
$ printf %b '\xef\xbb\xbfa'>a;dos2unix a;xxd -p a
dos2unix: converting file a to Unix format...
61
```

Answer (score 1):

Also answered on StackOverflow:  [How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240995/1320510) [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) has a good answer.

Short answer:

- Short answer: `sed -i $'1s/^\uFEFF//' file.txt`, but not on BSD or OS/X.
- Another answer: `vi file.txt`, `:set nobomb`, `:w`, simple but manual
- Install dos2unuix; `dos2unix -r file.txt`
- These marks have several possible meanings, including just that the file is UTF-8; see the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
- Windows programs love to add these marks.  Most editors will not remove these marks.